# Preserving Database Query Results After Form Submission

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have three drop down box with dynamic option form DB. They will load data to all three drop down boxes when page open. If one option is selected form Box-1, Box-2, Box-3 option will be updated/narrowed according to selection on Box-1. Same action will be happen when Box-2 option is selected.

But when I submit the form, all narrowed option in Box-2 and Box-3 are released and all option are shown as when start that page. Please give some suggestion to preserve my dynamically updated option on box-2 and box-3 after form submission.

INDEX:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
include("config.php");
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Search</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        function changeSecond(agm_branch){
            var xmlhttp;
            var designation = document.getElementById("designation").value;
            var office = document.getElementById("office").value;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                }

            else
                {// code for IE6, IE5 
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
                    var res=xmlhttp.responseText;
                    document.getElementById("designation").innerHTML=res;
                }
            }

            xmlhttp.open("GET","second_script.php?first="+agm_branch+"&second="+designation+"&third="+office,true);
            xmlhttp.send();

        }

        function changeThird(designation){
            var xmlhttp;
            var agm_branch = document.getElementById("agm_branch").value;
            var office = document.getElementById("office").value;

            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                }

            else
                {// code for IE6, IE5 
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
                    var res=xmlhttp.responseText;
                    document.getElementById("office").innerHTML=res;
                }
            }

            xmlhttp.open("GET","third_script.php?first="+agm_branch+"&second="+designation+"&third="+office,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }

</script>

<style>

</style>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<script src="script.js"></script>
<style>
BODY, TD {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
}
</style>    
</head>


<body>
<section class="register">

    <h1> Contact Book Search</h1>

    <div class="reg_section personal_info">

    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="POST" action="">
        <table width="1300" align="center" cellspacing="3" class="btable">

            <tr>
                <td width="179">NAME LOOKS LIKE:</td>
              <td width="1100"><input type="text" name="lst_name" id="lst_name" value="<?php echo stripcslashes($_REQUEST["lst_name"]); ?>" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td width="179" valign="middle"> AGM BRANCH: </td>
                <td width="1100">

                    <select id="agm_branch" name="agm_branch" onChange="changeSecond(this.value)">
                        <option value="">--</option>
                        <?php
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." GROUP BY agm_branch ORDER BY agm_branch";
                        $sql_result1 = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql);
                        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result1)) {
                        echo "<option value='".$row["agm_branch"]."'".($row["agm_branch"]==$_REQUEST["agm_branch"] ? " selected" : "").">".$row["agm_branch"]."</option>";}
                        ?>  
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>    
                <td width="179" valign="middle">DESIGNATION:</td>
                <td width="1100">


                    <select id="designation" name="designation" onChange="changeThird(this.value)">
                        <option value="">--</option>
                        <?php
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." GROUP BY designation ORDER BY designation";
                        $sql_result1 = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql);
                        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result1)) {
                        echo "<option value='".$row["designation"]."'".($row["designation"]==$_REQUEST["designation"] ? " selected" : "").">".$row["designation"]."</option>";}
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td width="179" valign="middle">OFFICE:</td>
                <td width="1100">


                    <select id="office" name="office">
                        <option value="">--</option>
                        <?php
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." GROUP BY office ORDER BY office";
                        $sql_result1 = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql);
                        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result1)) {
                        echo "<option value='".$row["office"]."'".($row["office"]==$_REQUEST["office"] ? " selected" : "").">".$row["office"]."</option>";}
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </td>

                <td><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Filter" /></td>

                <td>
                </label><a href=""> reset</a>
                </td>

            </tr>

        </table>




    </form>

    </section>
    </div>


    <table align="center" width="1300" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3" class="btable">

        <tr align="center" valign="middle">
            <td width="130" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>Last Name</strong></td>
            <td width="130" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>Calling Name</strong></td>
            <td width="180" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>Designation</strong></td>
            <td width="100" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>AGM Branch</strong></td>
            <td width="220" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>DGM Branch</strong></td>
            <td width="250" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>Office</strong></td>
        </tr>


        <?php
            if ($_REQUEST["lst_name"]<>'') {$search_last_name = " AND (last_name LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["lst_name"])."%' OR calling_name LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["lst_name"])."%')";}
            if ($_REQUEST["agm_branch"]<>'') {$search_agm_branch = " AND agm_branch='".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["agm_branch"])."'";}
            if ($_REQUEST["designation"]<>'') {$search_designation = " AND designation='".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["designation"])."'";}
            if ($_REQUEST["office"]<>'') {$search_office = " AND office='".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["office"])."'";}

            if ($_REQUEST["lst_name"]<>''OR $_REQUEST["agm_branch"]<>''OR $_REQUEST["designation"]<>'' OR $_REQUEST["office"]<>'') {
                $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE id>0".$search_last_name.$search_agm_branch.$search_designation.$search_office;


                $sql_result = mysql_query ($sql1, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql1);}
            if (mysql_num_rows($sql_result)>0) 
            {
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) 
                {
        ?>

                <tr valign="middle">
                    <td><?php echo $row["last_name"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["calling_name"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["designation"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["agm_branch"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["dgm_branch"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["office"]; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
                }
            } 
            else 
            {
                ?>
            <tr valign="middle"><td colspan="6">No results found.</td></tr>

            <?php   
            }
            ?>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

second_script.php:

```
<?php
    $first=$_GET["first"];
    $second=$_GET["second"];
    $third=$_GET["third"];
    //echo $first;
    $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");

   if (!$link)
   {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }
   if (mysql_select_db("ahamed", $link)){

        if ($first<>'') {$query1="SELECT * FROM data WHERE id>0 AND agm_branch='" .$first. "' GROUP BY designation ORDER BY designation";}
        else    {$query1= "SELECT * FROM data GROUP BY designation ORDER BY designation";}

      $data1=mysql_query($query1);

?>


    <select id="designation" name="designation">
    <option value="">--<option>
    <?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data1))
    {echo "<option value='".$row["designation"]."'".($row["designation"]==$second ? " selected" : "")."'>".$row["designation"]."</option>";}}
    ?>
    </select>
```

third_script.php:

```
<?php
    $first=$_GET["first"];
    $second=$_GET["second"];
    $third=$_GET["third"];
    echo $first;
   $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");

   if (!$link)
   {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }
   if (mysql_select_db("ahamed", $link)){


                if ($first<>'' && $second<>'') {$query= "SELECT * FROM data WHERE id>0 AND agm_branch='" .$first. "' AND designation='" .$second. "' GROUP BY office ORDER BY office";}
                else if ($first<>'' && $second=='') {$query= "SELECT * FROM data WHERE id>0 AND agm_branch='" .$first. "' GROUP BY office ORDER BY office";}
                else if ($first=='' && $second<>'') {$query= "SELECT * FROM data WHERE id>0 AND designation='" .$second. "' GROUP BY office ORDER BY office";}
                else    {$query= "SELECT * FROM data GROUP BY office ORDER BY office";}

        $data = mysql_query($query);

?>

    <select id="office" name="office">
    <option value="">--<option>

    <?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data))
    {echo "<option value='".$row["office"]."'>".$row["office"]."</option>";}}
    ?>
    </select>
```

Comment: did u check the console after post request is sent??it ll give an 500 error.in second_script.php you cannot put html inside php.you have to put the html outside php tags

Comment: Dear Bhadra, i have edited that code as exactly i have. my problem only with preserving data after submission. others working fine

Comment: can u post your full html code. after success you are appending <select id="designation" name="designation"> elemnent to document.getElementById("designation") .so now two elements with same id ,one inside other. in second_script remove the select tags

Comment: Dear Bhadra, please check updated full codes. thanks for the reply

Comment: when u are submitting the form it is posting to the same page .the page is kind of getting refreshed . the page is rendered newly. you are getting values based on options in javascript. when the page is refreshed .javascript also refreshes and that is why it is loading from first again

Comment: Dear Bhadra, is there any way to over come this issue? i very new to PHP and this stuffs?

Comment: move the search results php code at the bottom to another file, lets say search.php. remove the form ,if u are using form it ll refresh. now write a function in javascript just like u wrote for select change , send all three select box values to search.php on search  button click event using ajax .replace the table div with res from your request

Comment: i have another small issue, when i select value on drop down box-1, only box-2 getting update. how to make this to update box-3 also?

Answer (score 0):

actually You are using two ajax calls to get data

in your case make two ajax calls to both the scripts in changeSecond function and update the divs with results from the respective scripts

ill recommend to use library like jquery as u can make ajax calls easily with that with very less coding